# Pass x to a function and return y or vice versa without any conditional statement

Tags: javascript, function

Lets say I have,

```
var x=10;
var y=20;
```

Whenever I pass `x` to a function It must return `y`
or return `x` If I pass `y` without any conditional statement.

How can I do that ?

Comment: `function foo(x) { return {10:20, 20:10}[x];}` :)

Comment: emptyhua would you mind giving a small explanation of how this works? I don't think I've ever seen this syntax.

Comment: @JarneKompier: That's property access. `{10:20, 20:10}` is an object literal and `[x]` accesses the property that's the result of evaluating `x`.

Comment: @emptyhua is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @kamranrafi I can only think of this way

Comment: are the values of your variables always `10` and `20`?

Comment: @Puka Not always. It could be any.